# MissingMethodException in Grails with springSecurity

Tags: grails, spring-security

I need to bring the user in session but brings me null, if there is someone when in session

```
      groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
      general.Evento.findByAllAsistentes() is applicable for argument types:(general.Usuario) values: [null]
```

Now try it with .currentUser, and also with the .principal but I do not find it ...

```
    //def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
    def user = Usuario.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
    log.debug "User: ${user}" // Not found, it prints null

    Evento event = Evento.get(params.id)

     if(!event.findByAllAsistentes(user)){
                log.debug "Asistent to Event"
            }
```

I need your help, please

Answer (score 3):

`findByAllAsistentes` should probably be `findAllByAsistentes`, unless your Evento domain object has a property called `allAsistentes`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply so fast ... and I had not realized I had that error, I corrected, but still continues to make me the same error above, another recommendation please?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your `Evento` domain class.  Can you post that?